error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
I am trying to run a program that shows this error, I am not sure but it may have been due to an update. The error it shows is "error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64" which I believe says that I need a 32 bit version of the library. I ran
$sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
to which it says
libgfortran3 is already the newest version (6.4.0-17ubuntu1)
then I ran
$sudo apt-get install lib32gfortran3 libx32gfortran3
to which it says
E: Unable to locate package lib32gfortran3
E: Unable to locate package libx32gfortran3
I can not find the library anywhere. Can someone help me with this please?
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Please run file /path/to/program to find if it's 32 bit. The best thing is probably to recompile your program against appropriate versions.

Your provided details (if accurate) do show your system isn't fully updated, being behind on applying security fixes & other upgrades.. eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.6, but installed systems upgraded before that date.  I suggest applying fixes asap
